# How to group by items that can grow?

Tags: c#, linq

I am having difficulties with grouping lists. Here is what I have;

```
First column => second column
1            => 3,4
2            => 3,4
3            => 3,4,5
5            => 3,4
6            => 3,4,7
7            => 3,4
8            => 3,4,5
9            => 3,4,5
```

In my program, the first columns are Objects, and each one of the second columns are also Object List. So First Column(Object) has an IList

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the group of first columns that have the exact same second column; like this,

```
(the numbers are of the first column, I don't need the second column values)
    1,2,5,7 one group
    3,8,9 one group
    6 one group
```

But I couldn't find an efficient way to do this. I tried Linq but I don't know much about it.

Comment: Can't you simply use Linq `Group by` clause?

Comment: Can I? I am looking at group by syntax now, I can't say I understand it but since the numbers on the second column can grow, I didn't know how to write it. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put simply, this is the `GroupBy` expression which will do what you want:

```
var group = myList.GroupBy(
                     x => String.Join("|",x.SecondColumn), 
                     x => x.FirstColumn);
```

That groups by a concatenation of all the items in `SecondColumn` but selects `FirstColumn` as the group.

Test code:

```
var myList = new List<MyObject>(){
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 1, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4}},
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 2, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4}},    
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 3, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4,5}},    
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 5, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4}},    
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 6, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4,7}},    
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 7, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4}},    
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 8, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4,5}},    
            new MyObject{ FirstColumn = 9, SecondColumn = new List<int>{3,4,5}}
        };
var group = myList.GroupBy(x => String.Join("|",x.SecondColumn), x => x.FirstColumn);
foreach(var i in group)
    Console.WriteLine( String.Join(",",i));
```

Output

> 1,2,5,7
>   3,8,9
>   6

Live example: http://rextester.com/RFWLB54456

---

Edit after comments: You can change that `GroupBy`line to sort the elements of `SecondColumn`:

```
var group = myList.GroupBy(
                     x => String.Join("|",x.SecondColumn.OrderBy(n => n), 
                     x => x.FirstColumn);
```

Comment: Yes, this would rely on SecondColumn being ordered

Comment: I am having some trouble with it :( mine only returns 2|3 and I don't know why. Could it be because I don't have an Object like MyObject in your example, so I do the group by IList<FirstColumn>

Comment: @Ada - If you post your actual code as an update to the original question it would be easier to help

Comment: I know but the code and the objects are too long. The only difference between your code and mine is that I don't have a MyObject. I have a FirstColumn Object that stores IList<SecondColumn>. So I guess it only leaves me to do a simple group by then, right?

Comment: At minimum post the code for your `FirstColumn` object, without that im just guessing

Comment: Would it fit here it is 1947 lines and I don't think I am allowed to share it, sorry. I don't want to bother you anymore, you helped enough already. I think I should just learn the syntax of group by since you already showed me how to do it by appending the id's into a string which is the key to do this query. Thank you very much.